# Android - Facebook: an active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

i'm using this code:

```
if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

        try {
            String jsonUser = facebook.request("me");
            obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
            String id = obj.optString("id");
            String name = obj.optString("name");
            tv1.setText("sodfnsdf");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            tv1.setText("1");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv1.setText("2");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            tv1.setText("3");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            tv1.setText("4");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        tv1.setText("Error");
    }
```

i've searched online and in stackoverflow, but cannot find the answer to my question, i only found very similiar questions but different in some ways..

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to call facebook.authorize method

```
if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
facebook.authorize() }
```

For more information you can refer this link. I think it will help you.

Visit http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/integrate-facebook-logins-in-your-android-app/296